# What are the current trends in Software architecture apart from SOA

Tags: architecture

I know that SOA is an architecture pattern or style which is widely adopted. I also see Domain driven design is recommended by many people. Are there any other proven styles of architecture in current practice ?

If i had to talk for an hour on 'Current trends in Software architecture', which other methods apart from SOA should i touch upon.

Thanks,
Raj.

Comment: It all depends on what is your requirement. There is no golden hammer in architecture so please be specific in you question to get better answers.

Comment: @Faisal -- that golden hammer sounds useful in architecture, where can I get one ?

Comment: Ok, that is why i added the specific requirement - i may have to discuss currently successful trends. So which are they ?

Comment: The most successful, based on its wide-spread adoption and continued support, must certainly be the Big Ball of Mud! You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Trends" sounds a wee bit like "fashion" - as in "short lived", where as to me architecture has a bit more gravitas.  Having said that: people will always leap on to "new" ideas (re-package old ones) but it's sometimes hard to discern between genuine architecture "trends" and marketing / [Marchitecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchitecture) based ones.

Just to pick on SOA for a minute - SOA might seem like a new thing to some people - but to others it's [been around for a while](http://www.soapatterns.org/background.php) (2005 depending on how you look at it).

**Current trends in Architecture**

Here's some topics I'd do some research into if I was in your shoes:

- The Cloud: this is clearly gaining a lot of popular momentum; as the Cloud (or our Cloud based thinking) becomes more mature (and Cloud services become more of a commodity) it provides options not previously available or as accessible.
- Multi-Tenancey: with more and more services being delivered through shared servcies there's a clear benefit in being able to deliver these using a multi-tenancey based approach.